# Table layout with linear layout using all the screen height

Tags: java, android, tablelayout

I want to do:

```
****ROW 1****
****ROW 2****
****ROW 3****
LINEAR LAYOUT
```

I want to set 75% of the screen height for the table layout and 25% percent of the screen height for the linear laypout

how can i do that?

Comment: use layout weights wisely

Comment: @KaranMer how?? can you put an example?? thanks

Comment: check this out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Comment: @KaranMer linearlayout as the parent of both?

Comment: it will do give it a try first with your xml code just by removing layout height and width and setting weights to them

Comment: put your code so its easy to help